# function composition, interact and hackerrank exercises

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm new to Haskell and i'm now watching the ["Haskell Rank"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_D4P-KRNKs) series on youtube and i feel i need a better understanding of what's going on in the first video so i can move on.

He starts with the basic "solve me first" exercise on [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fp-solve-me-first/problem?isFullScreen=true), which already comes with the solution:

```
solveMeFirst a b = a + b

main = do
    val1 <- readLn
    val2 <- readLn
    let sum = solveMeFirst val1 val2
    print sum
```

this is clear, if i put it in a file, compile it and run it, it behaves as expected:

- takes two lines of input
- prints the sum of the numbers from the user input

---

through several steps of explaining the roles of each function, he reaches a more functional one-line solution;
he gets there by first working up to the following:

```
> show $ sum $ map read $ words "1 2"
3
```

Up until here, i understand everything, including the use of the ($) operator.

To finish, he then defines the main function, using `interact` to handle the input from `stdin`and there are two things i really don't understand:

1 - the function composition: he then reaches the solution of:

```
main = interact $ show . sum . map read . words
```

where he grabs the previous build up, removes the input `"1 2"` to compose the function that will be the argument for `interact`. And, what he doesn't explain thoroughly is "and replace all of its dollar signs with functional composition."

**Would love a detailed explanation of step-by-stepping this "inversion" process.**

2 - using this one-line solution, and compiling it from a file,

**how can i run the file, sending the input as `args`?**

Comment: `main` is not, actually, a function. It's a value of type `IO ()`. It is not *callable*, though it is *executable* by the Haskell runtime system.

Comment: i understand, but how do i pass my input when i run the file after compiling?

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez You run it just like the first one. Compile, execute, enter two lines of input with a number on each. The only difference is that you need to end the input after that -- on Linux, by pressing Ctrl+D; on Windows, I think by pressing Ctrl+Z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion to composition is based on the simple definition of the `.` operator (shown here using `$` to make the link clear).

```
(.) f g = \x -> f $ g x
```

`show . sum . map read . words` is the same as `\x -> show $ sum $ map read $ words x`.

The composed function is never explicitly applied to an argument because `interact` takes the function and produces an `IO ()` value which, when executed by the runtime, will apply the function to an argument also supplied by the runtime.

The runtime supplies the input by reading from standard input.

Comment: great explanation, i was trying to come up with `show (sum (map read (words x)))` but was missing the lambda... Can you just add an answer to the second question please?